# Is it True: The average distance of points from the diagonals is less than the average distance from circumference of the circle in a rectangular area

Tags: proof-writing, average, provability

My problem is related to proving that the average distance of random distributed points from the diagonals is less than the average distance from the circumference of the circle.

The problem is related to Computer Networking (specifically Wireless sensor Networks) where using a Diagonal over Circle is being proved. The statement in a published research paper states that-

> The average distance to the diagonal is smaller than the ring that leads the shorter request and response paths to the diagonal line than the circumference of the ring, which minimizes the energy consumption and decreases the delivery delay.
> [snapshot of the research paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUil0.jpg)

Full paper (GoogleDrive link): https://drive.google.com/file/d/15IyjkHEqk7QeuItHtAigVh6tc0bVaa8r/view?usp=sharing

[image: circle with center on the center of the rectangle]

The author has stated the result without any mathematical proof and I want to confirm if that is actually true for all cases or just some special case. I am pretty bad at math and can't even comprehend where to start.

Shape of the area is Rectangle and Points are Randomly scattered in the area

Comment: I can't access the paper. Can you pls share at least the equation. It's not quite clear how's the circle related to the rectangle.

Comment: At least for a square, this seems to be true. Take a square of side $2$. the average distance of points inside the square to the incircle is $\int_0^1\int_0^1 \left|\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-1\right| dx dy \approx 0.288794$ while the average distance to the two diagonals is $\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}} \approx 0.235702$ (the distance of CM of a right triangle with sides $1,1,\sqrt{2}$ to the hypotenuse).  For rectangle, it is not clear what circle one is supposed to use.

Comment: Hmm... if one allow to use circle with different radius. things can change. Let $r \le 1$ be the radius of a circle centered at origin, the average distance to that circle will be $$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left|\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-r\right| dxdy = \frac13(\sqrt{2} + \sinh^{-1}1) + \frac{\pi}{6}r^3 - r$$
This expression is minimized at $r = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ with a value $\approx 0.233273 < \frac1{3\sqrt{2}}$. Without knowing what circle the paper is talking about, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @EddyPiedadActually, the paper doesn't state any equations and just stated the statement in the introduction as a well known fact... That's why I have to ask such an ambiguous question...sorry for that

Comment: @achillehui Yes, the radius of the circle can be changed and optimized for least avg distance. 

If so, then the given statement doesn't hold true...right?

Comment: For a square, there isn't that many possible interpretation of the "circle". either it refer to the incircle, the circumcircle or a circle centered at center of square with varying radius. For the 3rd case, the statement does fail.

Comment: @EddyPiedad  I have replaced the paper link to one of my gdrive link... i think it will be accessible now.

Comment: @achillehui Thanks a lot :)